# What are some techniques for improving UI responsiveness?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, user-experience

In the example below, can anyone tell me how to make "slow response when clicked" respond more quickly without modifying appendContent()? I'm wondering if there's a way to place cheap operations before more expensive ones, and make sure the cheap ones actually get carried out quickly.

```
<div id="draw">slow response when clicked</div>

<div style="overflow: auto; height: 300px; border:solid 1px grey" id="content"></div>

<script language="javascript">

    var clickLink = document.getElementById("draw");
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content")

    function appendContent(){
        contentDiv.innerHTML =  contentDiv.innerHTML + "hello ";
    }

    clickLink.onclick = function(){
        clickLink.style.color = "red";
        for (var i = 0; i < 1500; i++){     
            appendContent();    
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: you might want to provide some code. :)

Comment: ok. I'm convinced. I'll code up an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanism for feedback should be different for the duration the user has to wait. Less than 0.1 seconds and a user will not notice.

Between 1 and 10 seconds you can simply display a symbol such as an animated gif of some sort that indicates your app is processing. See http://www.ajaxload.info/ 
I use a div with an ID "processing" and style it with a spinner and use the following jquery code to show and hide it before and after the process.

```
function showProcessing(){
    $("#processing").fadeIn("fast");
}

function hideProcessing(){
    $("#processing").fadeOut("fast");
}
```

Beyond 10 seconds it would be ideal to provide an estimate of processing time.

See [Response Time Overview](http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html) for the source of these numbers.

The following code immediately changes the link colour to red and calls the append method a fraction of a second later. Essentially is allows the browser to execute a separate thread before getting hung up in a loop. The timeout may need to be adjusted depending on the browser. Check out Neil Mix's [Threading in JavaScript 1.7](http://www.neilmix.com/2007/02/07/threading-in-javascript-17/) if you need to relinquish control in a more generic manner.

```
    function startAppend(){
      for     (var i = 0; i < 1500; i++){             
              appendContent();        
      }
    }

    clickLink.onclick = function(){
            clickLink.style.color = "red";
            setTimeout('startAppend()', 10)                
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. By this point, the data is already in the browser, I'm just redrawing a table. My problem is that the redraw seems to interfere with my "processing" graphic. Settimeout helps, but not that much.

Comment: Edit the question to share the code and perhaps we can optimize.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That does indeed work. I've been doing something similar on my non-example page, but I'm still getting some delay. I'll check it out. Thanks for the confirmation that setTimout really should work.

Comment: Would chaining setTimouts be a viable option when doing a really large screen redraw? For example, draw a table 100 rows at a time? Any examples of this anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is simply provide the user with some feedback so they know something's happening, you may try putting an animated gif - a loading circle or something, next to the button and disabling the button itself, then setting things back to normal after the redraw is complete.

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing something like that already. The problem is there's a delay between the click and the appearance of the graphic.

Answer (score 0):

since javascript don't have a good multithreading support, you need to split your dom operation into smaller parts. normally such things are done via performing long operation in the separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo User Interface Library has a lot of good code and controls which already use technologies such as AJAX to improve your web application's perceived responsiveness.

Using a library such as Yahoo!'s will made adding this functionality to your application much faster and less error prone.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add a div containing your loading graphic by default, but set the CSS to display:none. Then, when the div#draw is clicked, set the display of the loading graphic to block and then do your drawing. When the drawing is finished, set the display back to none.